# How best (idiomatically) to fail perl script (run with -n/-p) when input file not found?

Tags: perl

```
$ perl -pe 1 foo && echo ok
Can't open foo: No such file or directory.
ok
```

I'd really like the perl script to fail when the file does not exist.  What's the "proper" way to make -p or -n fail when the input file does not exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [-p switch](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-p) is just a shortcut for wrapping your code (the argument following -e) in this loop:

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
      ...             # your program goes here
  } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
  }
```

(-n is the same but without the continue block.)

The `<>` empty operator is equivalent to `readline *ARGV`, and that opens each argument in succession as a file to read from. There's no way to influence the error handling of that implicit open, but you can make the [warning it emits](https://perldoc.pl/perldiag#Can't-open-%25s:-%25s) fatal (note, this will also affect several warnings related to the -i switch):

```
perl -Mwarnings=FATAL,inplace -pe 1 foo && echo ok
```

Comment: @MarkReed inplace is the warnings category we are interested in. There is no reason to affect other warnings.

Comment: From [warnings](https://perldoc.pl/warnings#Fatal-Warnings): `The presence of the word "FATAL" in the category list will escalate warnings in those categories into fatal errors in that lexical scope.`

Comment: Right, `inplace` is the category; without it, `-Mwarnings=FATAL` means `FATAL => all`, which we don't want. got it.

Answer (score 4):

Set a flag in the body of the loop, check the flag in the END block at the end of the oneliner.

```
perl -pe '$found = 1; ... ;END {die "No file found" unless $found}' -- file1 file2
```

Note that it only fails when no file was processed.

To report the problem when not all files have been found, you can use something like

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $files = @ARGV} $found++ if eof; ... ;END {die "Some files not found" unless $files == $found}'
```

Comment: If your script is supposed to take files as arguments rather than read from stdin, an lighter alternative to this solution would be `BEGIN{die "File not found" unless -f $ARGV[0]}`.  (I say lighter, because it doesn't involve setting a flag and adding 2 pieces of codes)

Comment: Also assumes all files are of non-zero length.